# How do I get the parent city for a suburb using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Places Auto complete API. If I search for a particular suburb, let's say Richmond in Victoria, Australia I get the following address components returned:

```
0:Object
    long_name: "Richmond"
    short_name: "Richmond"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "locality"
        1: "political"

1: Object
    long_name: "Victoria"
    short_name: "VIC"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "administrative_area_level_1"
        1: "political"

2: Object
    long_name: "Australia"
    short_name: "AU"
    types: Array[2]
        0: "country"
        1: "political"
```

This is great, however Richmond is a suburb of Melbourne and for the purpose of my app I need to know this. How can I get the API to return the parent city if the locality is within one? If you look at the following URL you can see that it places Richmond in Melbourne, Victoria, Australia so I'm assuming it's possible somehow to get this information via the API?

https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Richmond&ftid=0x6ad64259018db945:0x5045675218ce810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the returned Latlng to reverse geocode: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 1):

Alas the City and/or Region info is not included in the Geocoding API return.

As a rough solution for location based searches I do km radius for city and region:

```
Worldwide   No filter
Country     Available from geocode
State       Available from geocode
Region      50 KM Radius from latlong
City        20 KM Radius from latlong 
Postcode    Available from geocode
Suburb      Available from geocode (Locality)
Radius      User defined radius from latlong
```

I did try using the 'bounds' values but without real success (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

If you need to be more accurate than that then you're making quite a large reference database.